# how to clear ImageUpload and Checkbox in ASP NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a sales page and setting up the Admin page at the moment. I have 4 Asp:Fileupload and three asp:checkboxes i want to clear when the user press the Add button.
I tried to search for the answer and looks like a foreach could fix it but i don't know what to write inside the ( ) . Can't find the right way to point out where the boxes are inside the AddProduct.aspx.cs .

The add method is called btnAdd_Click and the .aspx page is called AddProduct.aspx. The checkboxes is called chFD, ch30Ret and chCOD . The Fileupload is fulmg01, fulmg02, fulmg03.

Comment: `fulmg01.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();` for file upload and `chFD.Checked = false;` for checkbox should do the work

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment worked perfectly i am posting as answer.

`fulmg01.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();`

for file upload and

`chFD.Checked = false;`

for checkbox should do the work